# Heroku Scheduler With Python Script

Tags: python, heroku, scheduler

How do I run a python script that is in my main directory with Heroku scheduler?

Normally I run this through the command line with Heroku run python "script.py", but this syntax is clearly not correct for the Heroku Scheduler. Where it says "rake do_something" what should the correct syntax be to run a python script here? I've tried "python script.py" and this does not work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The Heroku Scheduler will try to run any command you give it. For Python, if you added a *mytask.py* to 
your app repo, you could have the Scheduler run:

```
python mytask.py
```

Instead of waiting for the Scheduler to run to see if the command works as expected, you can also test run it like this:

```
heroku run python mytask.py  # or heroku run:detached ...
heroku logs --tail
```

Another way to use the Scheduler would be to extend your app with a cli tool or a script runner that shares the app context. A popular one for Flask is [Flask-Script](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/).

Note: the "rake" references in the [Heroku Scheduler docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) example is for running tasks with [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).